# How do you access navbar css property from another component in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a navbar with this code:

```
<mdb-navbar SideClass="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-expand-lg scrolling-navbar py-0 navbar-dark lunada-gradient" [containerInside]="false">
```

How can I change the lunada-gradient property from another component in my case it is customizer. This is an example of an available option:

```
<div class="col">
    <span class="deep-space-gradient d-block rounded-circle" style="width:20px; height:20px;"
        data-bg-color="deep-space-gradient" [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedBgColor === 'deep-space-gradient'}" 
        (click)="changeNavbarBgColor('deep-space-gradient')">
  </span>
</div>
```

Component:

```
 selectedBgColor: string = 'lunada';selectedBgColor: string = 'lunada';

  options = {
    bgColor: 'lunada-gradient',
    layout: 'light'
  };

  constructor(
    private layoutService: LayoutService,
  ) {
    this.layoutSub = layoutService.customizerChangeEmitted$.subscribe(
      options => {
        if (options) {
          if (options.bgColor) {
            this.selectedBgColor = options.bgColor;
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }

  changeNavbarBgColor(color) {
    this.selectedBgColor = color;
    this.options.bgColor = color;

    this.layoutService.emitCustomizerChange(this.options);
  }

  options = {
    bgColor: 'lunada-gradient',
    layout: 'light'
  };

 changeNavbarBgColor(color) {
    this.selectedBgColor = color;
    this.options.bgColor = color;
    this.layoutService.emitCustomizerChange(this.options);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **modify** the CSS of another component, you cant use `::ng-deep` on your component, but need to be careful with this because it is easy to do a mess.

This is a simple example of how to do that

```
::ng-deep mdb-navbar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

If need more details about it, you can reed https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep